# Site-Wide global variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I am curious as to what is the best way to create a site-wide global variable in MVC3.

That is, a variable which is shared among multiple requests/visitors.

I'm guessing, that if this is possible the variable would be lost as soon as the site was recycled.. are there any other pros or cons of doing this?

The best thing to do would offcourse be to store everything in a database, but this is more of a is it possible/experiment kind of question ;)

Comment: The specific problem I want to experiment with is a small web based game in which visitors compete with each other and there is really no need to store the data in a database.

Comment: What kind of data, a dynamically changing string, the results of a database query, a compile time constant?

Comment: Given your description, in which what you're "sharing" really is data the site relies on, you really should make a database.  It's the best solution.

Comment: @Servy A class which runs a single thread and has a few calculated values that I want everyone to be able to access.

Comment: You should really factor out the data from the class that uses it.  Sharing the class that uses the data across various web requests isn't a good idea.  Even if you don't store the data in the database, that should be the only aspect of the "shared state".  You could consider using the cache to store that information though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered saving the data as XML in the App_Data folder?

You *could* create a singleton, but that's only a single instance per AppDomain. If you go 20 minutes without a hit, IIS will spin-down.

So the other real way is to persist the value somewhere - file or DB.

**Singleton Solution**

Here's the singleton pattern in C#.

```
public class MyValues
{
    private readonly static MyValues instance = new MyValues();

    private MyValues() { }

    public static MyValues Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldent that be slower than doing database requests?

Comment: If noone visits the site for 20 min, the values wouldent matter anyway so that might be a good solution